# What does "$\mathbb Q(\zeta _3)$ is covered by the union of the ellipse defined by $N(w-\gamma )$ for all $\gamma \in \mathbb Z[\zeta _3]$"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let \begin{align*}
N:\mathbb C&\longrightarrow \mathbb R_{\geq 0}\\
z=a+ib&\longmapsto z\bar z=a^2+b^2
\end{align*}
the norm application.
What does "$\mathbb Q(\zeta _3)$ is covered by the union of the ellipse defined by $N(w-\gamma )$ for all $\gamma \in \mathbb Z[\zeta _3]$" ?

Is $\mathbb Q(\zeta _3)$ a metric space ? What are ellipse in this space ? I precise that it's from a course of algebraic number theory. I really don't see what we are doing.

I precise that what we want to prove is that $\mathbb Z[\zeta _3]$ is an Euclidean ring.

Comment: Could you recall what $\zeta _3$ is ? $e^{2i \pi/3}$ ?

Comment: any primitive solution of $X^3-1=0$. So it can also be $\zeta _2=e^{4i\pi/3}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your metric space where you consider ellipses is the complex plane, and $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-3})$ and $\mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$ are embedded naturally in the complex plane.

---

Let me try to explain the whole proof. I think you want to see that the ring of Eisenstein integers $\mathbb{Z} [\omega]$ where $\omega = \frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}$ is a Euclidean domain with respect to the standard norm given by
$$N (m + n\omega) = m^2 + mn + n^2.$$
That is, that for every $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z} [\omega]$, $\beta \ne 0$, there exist $q,r \in \mathbb{Z} [\omega]$ such that $\alpha = q\beta + r$, and $r = 0$ or $N (r) < N (\beta)$.

The idea is to perform the division $\alpha/\beta$ in the fraction field $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-3})$ and then pick $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z} [\omega]$ that is close to $\alpha/\beta$:

**Lemma.** *For any $\alpha/\beta \in \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-3})$ there exists $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z} [\omega]$ such that $N (\alpha/\beta - \gamma) < 1$.*

Indeed, once we prove this lemma, we can write
$$\alpha = \gamma\,\beta + (\alpha/\beta - \gamma)\,\beta,$$
and $(\alpha/\beta-\gamma)\,\beta = \alpha - \gamma\,\beta \in \mathbb{Z} [\omega]$. Then,
$$N((\alpha/\beta - \gamma)\,\beta) = N(\alpha/\beta - \gamma) \cdot N(\beta) < N(\beta),$$
and we are done.

So how do we find an algebraic integer $\gamma$ as in the lemma? We note that the equation $N (z - \gamma) < 1$ for varying $z \in \mathbb{C}$ defines some open ellipse *on the complex plane*, centered in $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z} [\omega]$. So to prove the lemma, we should show that these ellipses for all $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z} [\omega]$ cover the whole complex plane (and hence $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-3})$).

---

**Exercise**: use the same argument with covering by ellispes to show that $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-1}]$, $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-2}]$, $\mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-7}}{2}\right]$, $\mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-11}}{2}\right]$ are Euclidean domains with respect to their usual norms.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you. I will stud all this and will make you know if I don't understand something. Thank you.